# Error creating trigger in Firebird

Tags: firebird

Trying to create a trigger to post an event in Firebird 2.5, and it's driving me nuts. Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trig FOR test
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
        POST_EVENT 'test_inserted';
END
-- there is a blank line here
```

I have this in a file, this is the error I get when trying to run it:

```
SQL> in test.sql;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Unexpected end of command - line 5, column 13
After line 0 in file test.sql
Expected end of statement, encountered EOF
```

When I try to type it in interactively, I get:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Token unknown - line 1, column 1
-END
```

Any ideas? I've verified that the table "test" indeed exists and has data in it. It seems like there's an error in my syntax but I can not figure it out to save my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each command in isql must end with a terminator symbol - by default that's a `;`, but since that is also used inside the trigger body as statement terminator, you need to change the terminator character to something else using the [`SET TERM`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-terminator) command. To change the terminator to `^` your script would be

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER test_trig FOR test
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
        POST_EVENT 'test_inserted';
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: Note that `SET TERM` is specific to ISQL (and some other utilities), it is not part of Firebird itself. If you would execute this trigger creation code using an API, then you should not use `SET TERM`.